# Expression.Call Skip or Take

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I made generic functionality that on run time it's compiling from **JSON filter** to **Expression** and have issue on make Skip and Take call, on my IQueryable, to be entire compiled (without **exec sp_executesql**) in SQL

My Method:

```
public static class PagingExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Page<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, QueryRequest queryRequest) where T : class
    {
        //if (queryRequest.Skip.HasValue)
        //{
          //query = query.Skip(queryRequest.Skip.Value);
        //}

        //if (queryRequest.Take.HasValue)
          //{
            //query = query.Take(queryRequest.Take.Value);
        //}
        var methodName = "Skip";
        var resultExp = Expression.Call(
            typeof(IQueryable),
            "Skip",
            Type.EmptyTypes,
            Expression.Constant(queryRequest.Skip.Value));

        query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);


        return query;
    }
}
```

Exception:

> InvalidOperationException: No method 'Skip' on type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' is compatible with the supplied arguments.

Comment: [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2) is not an instance method of `IQueryable`, but an extension method in the static `Queryable` class. Hence the call must have _target_ `Queryable` and the first **argument** will be your `query`.

Comment: Also `Type.EmptyTypes` is not correct, because you calling `Queryable.Skip<T>(query, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2) method is not an instance method of `IQueryable`, but an extension in the static `Queryable`class.

You need to get the generic method info and pass the source query as first argument:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Skip").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
var resultExp = Expression.Call(
                       method,
                       query.Expression, 
                       Expression.Constant(queryRequest.Skip.Value));
```

Comment: Why `Expression.Constant(query)` instead of `query.Expression`?

Comment: If using `Expression.Constant(query)` -> `Exception: value entityType can not be null`

If using `query.Expression` -> its working but its with `sp_executesql 'OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS',N'@__p_0 int',@__p_0=0' `I'm trying to achieve without `sp_executesql` but i think is EF issue already

Comment: @AleksAndreev `Expression.Constant(query)` worked in my test, but I guess you're right with `query.Expression`... edited the answer

Comment: What's the difference from `query = query.Skip(queryRequest.Skip.Value);`?

Comment: @IvanStoev omg, that's typical for me to forget to take a step back and look again...I'm not sure if OP's real problem requires to create the expression by hand, but as the question stand I think you're right that this is simply `query.Skip(...)` as you said.

Answer (score 2):

It is thowing that exception because there is no Skip method in the IQueryable interface.

You should use the [Queryable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=netframework-4.7.2) class that provides a set of static methods (including Skip) for querying data structures that implement IQueryable.

Regards.